# Separate string from list C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have list of string and each of that strings in list look like this: `sim_pin: 1234`. List have 24 strings, and I wanna to get each of that strings, separate string where separator will be `:` ( : and space), and save to list only that part who is right from separator.

**EDIT:** 
Here is my code

```
string url = @"E:\Sims.log";
    public static IEnumerable<DiverGate> GetData(string url)
    {
        Stream stream = File.Open(url, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
            string[] lines = Regex.Split(str, "\r\n");

            List<string> lista = new List<string>();
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                lista.Add(line);
            }

            List<string> header = lista.GetRange(0, 23);

            //I stop here and im out of idea
        }
   }
```

Comment: and where is the problem? and what have you tried ?

Comment: Show a larger example of the list please, how are they delimited? Is it literally a list (`List<String>`) or a list as in a `string` with a list of values in it.

Comment: Methods of `System.String` will help you for sure. Take a look at `Split()` and `Trim()` to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

where input is your original list of strings

```
        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        input.ForEach(x=> output.Add(x.Split(new[] {": "},StringSplitOptions.None).Last()));
```

Comment: Tnx bro, this code do some serious things in my code

Comment: Anytime bud, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

```
var List1 = new List<string>{"sim_pin: 1234", "sim_pin: 2345", "sim_pin: 3456"};
var List2 = new List<string>();
foreach (var s in List1) {
    var ns = s.Split(':')[1].TrimStart(' ');
    List2.Add(ns);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    for ( int i =0; i< yourList.Count(); i++) {

        string s = yourList[i];
        int i = s.indexOf(":");
        s = s.Substring (i);
        yourList.Insert(i, s);
}
```